# Magento 2 Adding field to Account information tab at admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer-account, uicomponent, addfield

I have added new customer attribute 'Company' (not to customer_address) and I need to render this in customer_form ui-component at the "Account information" tab.

It's already in customer collection when I check this in magento_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php
[image]

For implementing
I have added to *magento_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml* following:

```
    <field name="company" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

I also tried:

```
        <field name="company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

But this field doesn't appear at the account information tab!
What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @Stepan did you added the custom field.

Comment: @shivashankarm yes

Comment: Please refer the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261433/add-a-custom-fields-account-information-section-magento2-dashboard?noredirect=1#comment368965_261433

Comment: i would like to add in frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you doing wrong when you created customer attribute. No need to additional xml for that. Try following code which create mobile attribute and added **account information** tab automatically.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
            $this->createMobileAttribute($setup);
        }
    }

    public function createMobileAttribute($setup)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'mobile',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Mobile',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 1000,
                'position'              => 1000,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'default'               => '0'
            ]
        );

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sohel Rana in which file i have to add the above code in my custom module

Comment: Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\UpgradeData.php

Comment: Hi @sohel thanks for your reply, I would like add a custom field in myaccount dashboard frontend section not in admin :

Comment: Please refer the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261433/add-a-custom-fields-account-information-section-magento2-dashboard?noredirect=1#comment368965_261433

Comment: Hi @sohel now iam able to add fields account information section but the values are not saving in which table i have to check.

Comment: How ca you remove?