# Add a custom fields account information section magento2 dashboard

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard

We would like to a custom text field in my account dashboard account infomation section using custom module in magento2

Please find the screenshot below:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: input field add or only label show

Comment: its a date field

Comment: have u  created custom customer  attribute?

Comment: No iam not added iam just installed custom module

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two attributes
2. Create two fields this template

Now register event listener.

> **VendorName/Customer/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_edited">
        <observer name="vendorname_customer_account_edited" instance="VendorName\Customer\Observer\CustomerAccountEdited"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> **VendorName/Customer/Observer/CustomerAccountEdited.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerAccountEdited implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * CustomerAccountEdited constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $email = $observer->getEvent()->getEmail();
        $customerData = $this->request->getPostValue();
        if(isset($customerData['phone_number']) && $customerData['phone_number']) {
            try {
                $customerObj = $this->customerRepository->get($email, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                $customerObj->setCustomAttribute('mobile', $customerData['mobile_country_code'].$customerData['phone_number']);
                $this->customerRepository->save($customerObj);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Update]

For geting value from template use class method or create helper method.

Ex:

```
public function getCustomerMobile($customer)
{
    $mobile = $customer->getCustomAttribute('mobile');
    if(!$mobile) {
        return '';
    }

    $mobile = $mobile->getValue();
    return $mobile;
}
```

Comment: Create two attributes

    Create two fields this template

Comment: We need to create those progrmatically in our custom module right?

Comment: Yes, create a setup script for creating attributes.

Comment: can you please share the exact setupschema code  and locations

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212902/magento-2-adding-field-to-account-information-tab-at-admin-panel

Comment: Thanks @sohel Also please share the code of calling custom attributes in template file

Comment: check updated answer.