# Magento2.3: How to add additional fields in My Account page?

Tags: magento2.3, myaccount

I need to add additional fields in the Account information section on My Account page.

In order to do that, where I have to add the code?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code which creates `Customattribute` attribute and added **account information** tab automatically.

For that, you need to create one file at **Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\UpgradeData.php** and paste below code and change attribute Name and code as per your need.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $this->createCustomAttribute($setup);
        }
    }

    public function createCustomAttribute($setup)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add new customer attribute
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'customattribute',
            [

                'label'                 => 'Customattribute',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'required'              => false,
                'sort_order'            => 1000,
                'position'              => 1000,
                'visible'               => true,
                'system'                => false,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'default'               => '0'
            ]
        );

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customattribute');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Solution provided by Sohel Rana at this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212909/67044). So, if it's working then you must thanks him.